# How to launch jQuery lightbox2 on page load?

Tags: jquery, popup, lightbox2

i am using [LightBox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) for image gallery in my site and now i want to show a image like a POP UP on Load page . i want to bind the image or code in a hidden tag and run it as click triger .

Comment: at the end of all your lightbox loading do `$(image).trigger('click')`...

Comment: Have you tried [`$.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: Pedro i did not get you that what are you talking about. you mean i have to put this code in lightbox javascript file ?

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#popimg").trigger('click')});</script>

Comment: i am trying this but its affect my page show blank white page

Comment: Please, edit your post with relevant parts of your code. It would be easier to know what's going on.